# Content Controls getting lost when loading docx file via OOXML into another Word document

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js

I have a Word Add In that loads a Word document into the current document. This is working just fine with the below code.

```js
var myOOXMLRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
var myXML;
myOOXMLRequest.open('GET', 'template.xml', false);
myOOXMLRequest.send();
if (myOOXMLRequest.status === 200) {
  myXML = myOOXMLRequest.responseText;
}

Word.run(function (context) {
  Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(myXML, { coercionType: 'ooxml' });
});
```

Now I added some content controls to the Word document which I saved as template.xml (that serves as my template). When I now save the Word document containing the content controls as XML, and try to load it via the above code snippet, all works fine but the content contros are gone! I can't access them from Word, nor can I access them via Javascript like so:

```js
var name = context.document.contentControls.getByTitle('myContentControl');
context.load(name);

return context.sync().then(function () {
  var nameNew = name.items[0];
  nameNew.insertText("Test", "Replace");

  return context.sync().then(function () {
  });
});
```

Is this a bug or is this just not possible? I also thought about putting some placeholders like ##myValue## into the Word template and then replacing those with values, but I'd rather do it with ContentControls if that is possible.

**EDIT:**
Here is the XML that I have created from my template: http://pastebin.com/NX0ZqLiM

I created the XML by just saving the Word document as XML and then loading as described above. Funny thing is, when I run the sample now I can see the content controls in Word. But when I try to access them via Javascript the ContentControl collection is always empty. I used a code sample from here https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/contentcontrol?product=word to try to access the content controls, but the collection of items is always empty.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: If you do place ##myValue## into the control do they insert correctly?

Comment: No, what I meant was instead of content controls I could use this # notation as a placeholder to replace (assuming content controls are not working at all in this scenario). Sorry for the confusion

Comment: not sure i understand your question. are you saying that the template.xml is the one that includes the content controls? or you are inserting the content controls after the ooxml insertion?  if the first, would be great if you can provide the sample OOXML you are using.

Comment: The template.xml is the one that includes the Content Controls, but after inserting it via OOXML insertion they are all gone. I'll provide the OOXML once I get home, will edit the question then.

Comment: thanks! it will be awesome if you can tell me how you generated the XML as well. thanks

Comment: I have updated the post with a link to the XML, how I generated it and how I tried to access the content controls programmatically via JS.

Comment: I'm trying similar thing with header/footer in XML. I've come to the conclusion that setSelectedDataAsync may not be the right way to approach this. setSelectedDataAsync targets the current selection, that means any part of your XML outside of the main section will be rejected.